# Named let in Scheme

Tags: guile

I am attempting to write a loop in Scheme using named let. I would like to be able to break out of the iteration early based on various criteria, rather than always looping right at the end. Effectively, I would like to have `while`, `break` and `continue`. I am constrained to use guile 1.8 for strong reasons, and guile 1.8 does not implement the R6RS `while` construct. My question is, does recursing using named let have to be tail recursive, and why can't you restart the loop before the end? [Does this need a code example?] When I do attempt to recurse using an early exit at several point with IO operations I invariably read past EOF and get unpredictable corruption of data.

Comment: It would be useful to show what you've tried so far. You mention `while`, `break` and `continue`: it sounds as if you're trying to import imperative ideas (C-style) into a non-imperative language, and thus trying to write _extremely_ unidiomatic scheme.

Comment: (and regarding your specific questions: no, recursing doesn't have to be a tail call; yes, you can restart the ‘loop’ at any point; and yes, a code example would help)

Comment: Except that Guile 2 sees fit to incorporate the while construct as a new feature. My context is in fact Guile. Guile is indeed for integrating with C/C++ code and this sort of imperative thing does come up from time time. We are not talking 'pure' Scheme here (if you see what I mean).

Comment: No, but if your system expects you to control the C/C++ code using Guile, then it (presumably) expects you to program that Guile layer in a Guile-idiomatic way. If you're looking for `break` and `continue`, you'll look for a long time, since there are no immediate analogues of those in schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(let name ((iter iter-expr) (arg1 expr1) (arg2 expr2))
  (cond
    (continue-predicate (name (next iter) arg1 arg2)))
    (break-predicate break-expression-value)
    (else (name (next iter) next-arg1-expression next-ar2-expression))))
```

A continue is just calling again using most of the same arguments unchanged except the iterated parts which will change to the next thing.

A break is a base case.

So what is a `while`? It is a named `let` with a break predicate and a default case.

Scheme doesn't really have a `while` construct. If you read the report you'll see that it is just a syntax sugar (macro) that turns into something like a named `let`.

You need it to be tail recursive if you want to be able to exit it without all the previous calculations to be done. You can also use `call/cc` to supply an exit continuation which is basically having Scheme doing it for you under the hood. Usually `call/cc` is quite far out for beginners and it takes some time to master so making your procedures tail recursive is easier to understand than doing something like this:

```
(define (cars lists-of-pair)
  (call/cc (lambda (exit)
    (fold (lambda (e a)
            (if (pair? e)
                (cons (car e) a)
                (exit '()))) ; throw away continuations to make current result make it ()
          '()
          lists-of-pair)))

(cars '((1 2) (a b))) ; ==> (1 a)
(cars '((1 2) ()))    ; ==> ()
```

Comment: Of course you mean 'So what is a while? It is a named let with a continue predicate and a default case.'

Comment: @andro a `while` is doing recursion if a predicate is true so you can think of it as recursion unless a negated base case hits. Thus `break` with `(not while-predicate)` as predicate. `continue` usually has recursion, like the default case, but with less calculations.